# Elasticsearch filtered aggregations, returned bucketed keys are not split up specifically

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have many file assets stored across multiple folders. What I'm trying to do is run a text string query on this set of filenames, return the matched file parameters, and how often it appears in each folder. However with the attached query, I am not getting the full filename parameters for each filtered result:

Here's the query:

```
  "aggs": {
    "filenames": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {"filename": "foo"} 
      },
      "aggs": {
        "files_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "filename",
            "size": 100
          },
          "aggs": {
            "folder_count": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "folder"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

And results looks like something this:

```
"aggregations": {
        "filenames": {
            "doc_count": 1218,
            "files_count": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "foo",
                        "doc_count": 1218,
                        "folder_count": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 1139,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "1575569706838",
                                    "doc_count": 8
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "1575656106314",
                                    "doc_count": 8
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "1575742506771",
                                    "doc_count": 8
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "1575828907233",
                                    "doc_count": 8
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "1575915306570",
                                    "doc_count": 8
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "1576001707455",
                                    "doc_count": 8
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "1576088108154",
                                    "doc_count": 8
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "1576174506235",
                                    "doc_count": 8
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "1576347307560",
                                    "doc_count": 8
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "1576260907130",
                                    "doc_count": 7
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
...
```

Here is a sample of my index data:

```
{
    "screens": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "date": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "extension": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "filename": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    },
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "folder": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    },
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "format": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "path": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key: queryString returned is only a partial, or different snippet of a filename field. What do I need to include in order to get the fully matched filename in this query? Ideally instead of key: queryString, I'd like to separate it by unique filenames instead of matching everything together. Do I need another level of aggs for filenames between the filtered results and folders? How would I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your index mapping please?

Comment: Added sample index, is that what you're asking for? Thanks.

Comment: I'm asking about your index mapping, i.e. what you get from `GET your-index-name`

Comment: Ok added in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filename` field is most probably of type `text`, hence analyzed and indexed into tokens, which is why your bucket keys are the way they are.

You need to run the terms aggregation on the `filename.keyword` sub-field, like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "filenames": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "filename.keyword": "queryString"          <---- change the field name here
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "files_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "filename.keyword",             <---- change the field name here
            "size": 100
          },
          "aggs": {
            "folder_count": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "folder.keyword"            <---- change the field name here
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: Yes that works! I did update the mapping for filename so I am able to use `"filename": "queryString" ` instead of `"filename.keyword": "queryString" `Thanks